# Gzip compression on IIS - Can't get it to work

Tags: iis, gzip, iis-10

I have an existing IIS application, and I am trying to get GZIP server side compression to work. The application runs on EPIServer CMS (which I am not that familiar with) - Thinking this could be related to the CMS somehow, as a first step...

I decided to create a new IIS application and this time using Umbraco (another CMS that I am very familiar with) - I have created a basic page with some CSS files and images,

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

header.

This is what I have tried and checked.

1. Working locally, I am running windows 10. and IIS 10
2. I have enabled Dyamic Content Compression and Static Content Compression under Internet Information Services > Performance Features in Windows Features
3. For the locally set up website in IIS I have ensured that the compression section has both Enable Dynamic & Static check boxes are ticked.
4. In my web-config file I have added this single line

   ```
   <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
   ```

When the Webconfig has this line I inspect the headers in my browser:

**REQUEST HEADERS**

```
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Host: umbracotest.site
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://umbracotest.site/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36
```

**RESPONSE HEADERS**

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Tue, 01 May 2018 15:09:02 GMT
ETag: "03739d0e978d31:0"
Last-Modified: Tue, 19 Dec 2017 16:52:54 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

5. If I change that webconfig line slightly - dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" to true - *then I just get a whole bunch of symbols in the browser - does that mean anything?*
6. If I add a few more lines in to my webconfig to look like this:

   `<system.webServer> 
       <httpCompression>
         <staticTypes>
           <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="image/png" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="image/svg" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
         </staticTypes>
         <dynamicTypes>
           <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" />
           <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
         </dynamicTypes>
         <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" 
         dynamicCompressionLevel="8" />
       </httpCompression>
       <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" 
        dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />`

headers are still the same.

7. C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\MYAPPPOOL-NAME << this folder is created but empty.

This is a ASP.net MVC application
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried to clear the cache ? (Ctrl + F5)

Comment: Yes... tried... that. About to do a hello world style tutorial for GZIP, maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after banging my head on the wall for about 8 hours, I finally got it to work!

After checking everything twice, reading every post I could find on the topic, I came across a comment to a similar question that suggested it could be something to do with my antivirus software. I'm working in an enterprise environment and I don't have the rights to disable it on my local machine. So I deployed the code to our staging server......... and it works.

So in case someone else has this problem, try and disable your anti-virus and see if that makes any difference, it worked for me.